# Is there a way to add a SharePoint group to a SharePoint calendar event to speed up adding long lists of people?

Tags: 2013

We have Communities or Practice or large project teams that use SharePoint calendars to manage their events. Entering calendar events for long lists of people one at a time is tedious and slow. Is there a way to use SharePoint groups or Outlook Distributions Lists to speed up the process of adding large numbers to people to new calendar events?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Attendee** column for this purpose. By default this column is not available. The process to add an Attendee column is:

Go to List Settings and click on Event in the Content Type section. Then click on "Add from existing site or list columns". Choose Attendee from the list columns and click on Add.

After that Attendee column will be available to event **NewForm.aspx** and You can add groups or users to that field.